# SQL Server Active Record counts by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've created a database storing Incident tickets.
I have created a fact and a number of dimension tables.

Here is some sample data

```
+---------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
| LastModifiedDateKey | TicketNumber |    Status    | factCurrent |    Date    |
+---------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
|                2774 | T:9992260    | Open         | 1           | 4/12/2017  |
|                2777 | T:9992805    | Open         | 1           | 7/12/2017  |
|                2777 | T:9993068    | Open         | 1           | 7/12/2017  |
|                2777 | T:9993098    | Open         | 0           | 7/12/2017  |
|                2793 | T:9993098    | Acknowledged | 0           | 23/12/2017 |
|                2928 | T:9993098    | Closed       | 1           | 5/01/2018  |
|                2777 | T:9993799    | Open         | 0           | 7/12/2017  |
|                2928 | T:9993799    | Closed       | 1           | 5/01/2018  |
|                2778 | T:9994729    | Open         | 1           | 8/12/2017  |
|                2774 | T:9994791    | Open         | 0           | 4/12/2017  |
|                2928 | T:9994791    | Closed       | 1           | 5/01/2018  |
|                2777 | T:9994912    | Open         | 1           | 7/12/2017  |
|                2778 | T:9995201    | Open         | 0           | 8/12/2017  |
|                2793 | T:9995201    | Closed       | 1           | 23/12/2017 |
|                2931 | T:9718629    | Open         | 1           | 8/01/2018  |
|                2933 | T:9718629    | Closed       | 1           | 10/01/2018 |
|                2932 | T:9855664    | Open         | 1           | 9/01/2018  |
|                2931 | T:9891975    | Open         | 1           | 8/01/2018  |
+---------------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+------------+
```

I want a query that will give me the total of tickets open at the end of each month.
In the data January should have 8 and Feb 2.
Note: that a ticket can have multiple rows with same status because a dimension key has changed or multiple rows with different status all in the same month. e.g. T:9993098.

Comment: Thanks for the table edit :)

Comment: I can use this query to get the correct value for Jan.
Select count(distinct TicketNumber)
  FROM [dbo].[factTicket] ft
  inner join [dbo].[dimService] ds
  on ft.ServiceKey=ds.ServiceKey
  inner join dimDate dd
  On ft.LastModifiedDateKey=dd.dateKey
  where date < '2018-01-01'
 and TicketNumber NOT IN 
(SELECT Distinct TicketNumber
  FROM [dbo].[factTicket] ft
  inner join [dbo].[dimService] ds
  on ft.ServiceKey=ds.ServiceKey
  inner join dimDate dd
  On ft.LastModifiedDateKey=dd.dateKey
  where Status in ('Resolved','closed','Cancelled')
  and date < '2018-01-01'
)

Answer (score 2):

This approach first uses `ROW_NUMBER` to identify the most recent record for each ticket, for each month/year.  It is assumed that the most recent record in a month will contain the status in which a ticket ended for that month.  Then, it aggregates over this modified table, counting only tickets which ended the month in an open status.

```
SELECT
    YEAR(Date) + "-" + MONTH(Date) AS date,
    COUNT(*) AS num_open_tickets
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date), TicketNumber
                           ORDER BY BY Date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1 AND t.Status = 'Open'
GROUP BY
    YEAR(Date) + "-" + MONTH(Date);
```

Comment: I tried this and not sure about the t2.status = 'Open' 
Do you just mean t.Status= 'Open'

Comment: @JoeFuller Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: Hi,
Apologies the question is slightly wrong I want an accumulated total.
In the data January should have 8 and Feb 10!! As the December tickets are still open.

Comment: Maybe you should open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would generate the months.  Then do a cumulative count of the opens minus the closes.  Alas, that is a bit tricky because of the repeated rows for a ticket and because you are using an old version of SQL Server.

But . . . you can do this:

```
with months as (
      select dateadd(day, 1 - day(min(date)), min(date)) as mon_start,
             max(date) as max_date
      from sample
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, mon_start), max_date
      from months
      where dateadd(month, 1, mon_start) < max_date
     )
select m.mon_end,
       (select count(distinct case when status = 'Open' then ticket end) -
               count(distinct case when status = 'Closed' then ticket end)
        from sample s
        where s.date <= m.mon_end
       ) as open_tickets
from (select dateadd(day, -1, mon_start) as mon_end
      from months
     ) m;
```

This uses a recursive CTE to generate the months.  It is easier to generate the first day of the months and then subtract one day afterwards (what is the date when you add 1 month to the last day of February?)

The rest uses a correlated subquery to count the number of open tickets on that date.

Comment: I have SQL Server 2016 so any enhancements you can make would be good.

Comment: @JoeFuller . . . I would suggest that you ask another question.  The capabilities of the two products are quite different and this question already has two answers.

Comment: Hi,
sorry first question on here. Did I put incorrect tag? 
As I can't see reference to any version here.

Comment: You tagged with `sql-server-2008` ... is that not clear to you?

Comment: Not once it's posted no.